# Why does Facebook batch API request sometime return nulls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

I use Facebook's batch request quite a bit in my app.  For the most part, it works really well, but one thing that confuses me is why does their API sometimes return nulls?  If I get this "nulls" response, I can just try again moments later and it will work.

Here's an example:

**URL:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token={access_token}
```

**Request Body (prior to encoding):**

```
batch=[{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{page_id}?return_ssl_resources=1"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{page_id}?return_ssl_resources=1"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{page_id}?return_ssl_resources=1"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{page_id}?return_ssl_resources=1"}]
```

**Here's what Facebook sometimes returns:**

```
[null,null,null,null]
```

**If I make the same request a second later, I get the proper response:**

```
[{"code":200,"headers":[...headers here...],"body":{...body here...},{"code":200,"headers":[...headers here...],"body":{...body here...},{"code":200,"headers":[...headers here...],"body":{},{"code":200,"headers":[...headers here...],"body":{...body here...}}]
```

The behavior is not always consistent.  Most of the time I can try again and get a proper response.  Occasionally I need to try 2 to 3 times.  This problem happens dozens of times a day and it's been going on as long as I can remember.  I checked my App diagnostics on Facebook and my App doesn't have any restrictions, there's no API throttling, and Facebook doesn't even list these under their "API Errors" report.  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Could be unrelated, but someone just asked the exact same question a few minutes ago: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9280629/some-responses-are-null-when-making-batch-requests-but-they-are-all-independe

Comment: If two people are asking the same thing, maybe Facebook introduced a bug into the api.  Have you check the bugs?

Comment: It's been happening since at least January 21.  I can't find a bug filed for it, so I'll go and file one now.

Comment: Just filed a bug. If anyone else experiences this problem, please vote on this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295201867209494

Comment: @JohnnyO I have started to see this bug again but I see this happening for deletion of app generated app requests in batch mode. I have logged a separate bug for this as I am not sure if it is really the same issue that you were facing as you seem to be getting it only with get. My newly logged bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/497407853617264

Comment: Hi @DivKis01, it seems that the bug has appeared again and a new bug report has been filed here as well: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/186195978183379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this problem has corrected itself. I haven't seen this error show up for a few days now.

Bug report here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295201867209494?browse=search_4f42b29071ebc7f92807017